# Blazor Server-side not loading event listeners

Tags: html, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm building a Blazor Server-side website and I'm using a template for the design. This includes CSS and JavaScript files.

For some reason the event listeners are not working! I have a button that uses CSS and JavaScript to do some stuff. If I start the website then nothing happens when I press the button. But if I then refresh the page with CTRL+F5 then it works!

I'm using .NET Core 3.1.

**Normal F5 refresh of the website (don't work):**

[image]

**CTRL+F5 refresh of the website (now it works):**

[image]

**_Host.cshtml**

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Title</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/vendor.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/theme.css">
<script src="js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/theme.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: seeing as those events are being attached by vendor.min.js we cannot know really - does that js package require some kind of initialisation? If so, where are you doing that?